# Using git to see all logs related to a specific file extension within subdirectories

Tags: git, git-log

I am trying to see the commits in the history of a repository but just for files with an specific extension.

If this is the directory structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── a.txt
├── b
└── subdir
    ├── c.txt
    └── d
```

And this is the full history:

```
$ git log --name-only --oneline 
a166980 4
subdir/d
1a1eec6 3
subdir/c.txt
bc6a027 2
b
f8d4414 1
a.txt
```

If I want to see logs for file with .txt extension:

```
$ git log --oneline *.txt
f8d4414 1
```

It returns only the file that is in the current directory, not in subdirectories. I want to include all possible subdirectories inside the current directory.

I've also tried:

```
$ git log --oneline */*.txt
1a1eec6 3
```

And:

```
$ git log --oneline *.txt */*.txt
1a1eec6 3
f8d4414 1
```

That works for this case, but it is not practical for more generic cases.

And:

```
$ git log --oneline HEAD -- *.txt
f8d4414 1
```

Without success.

Comment: Does it have to be a git solution, or could you simply grep the list?

Comment: Yes, I need to use git because I am writing an script that uses other git commands with more options, and I don't want git to process all files, just the ones with a specific extension.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try:

```
git log --oneline -- '*.txt'
```

The `--` is used to indicate only positional arguments will follow.  And `'*.txt'` searches all folders from the current directory on down.

Alternatively, you could limit the results by starting the search in a subdirectory, e.g. `-- 'sub/*.txt'`.

Comment: Thanks! It is weird because it works without simgle quotes with *.java, and *.rb extension.

Comment: Thanks @hector!  I didn't realize the quotes were optional.  I'll add that to the response.

Comment: it it is not optional for '*.txt' extension if you want to check also subdirectories. I just tried in git version 1.9.1.

Comment: thanks @hector - it works on my machine without the quotes...not sure what's going on there...either way, I'll remove the ambiguity from my response (at least we know it works with the quotes)

Comment: Without the quotes it will be expanded by your shell before git sees it.

Comment: Thanks @TavianBarnes - does that suggest some shells may interpret the (unquoted) command differently from other shells?

Comment: Yes.  For example my shell will give an error if I write `*.txt` and there are no such files in the working directory.  Other shells will pass a literal `*.txt` along if it couldn't be expanded.  And still other shells may remove the `*.txt` from the command line completely if it doesn't match.

Comment: I am using GNU bash version 4.3.11. I tried `find . -name *.txt` and it doesn't return .txt file from subdirectories, but `find . -name '*.txt'` does. When I tried `find . -name *.rb` with ruby extension and without quotes, it searches in subdirectory. As `git` uses a lot of shell scripts it might be using `find` command at some extent.

Comment: @hector You'll understand better what's going on if you do `echo find . -name *.txt` vs `echo find . -name '*.txt'`.

Comment: Detail: the '--' is not used for path specification, but it ["signifies the end of command options"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/66883).

Comment: The shell will expand `*.txt` to the files in the current working directory, unless there are no files to expand in which case the shell will pass `*.txt` as an argument.  Putting `'*.txt'` means the shell will not expand the argument.  That's why sometimes the single-quote was unnecessary, but sometimes was needed.