# git - how to find commits which reference specific file extensions that do NOT exist in the source code anymore

Tags: git

I need to find all commits in `git log` which are referencing some old binaries with extensions `.jar` and `.class`.

We did have those files in the source code but **not** anymore!
However, I need to find all the **commits** which were referencing some of the files with that extension (for example **test.class** although I do not know the exact names of those files, just their extensions). I need to filter the commits that did some modification on files with extension **.class** for example. I do NOT want to filter commits based on the commit message.

I tried with:

```
git log --oneline -- '*.class'
```

in relation to this link:
[Using git to see all logs related to a specific file extension within subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665183/using-git-to-see-all-logs-related-to-a-specific-file-extension-within-subdirecto)

but without luck (no result)

Is this my requirement achievable?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: try with `--all` as an option also.

Comment: @eftshift0 can you put the whole syntax? `git log --oneline --all -- '*.class'`

Comment: @eftshift0 it seems this helped! You're amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git stores every commit forever (or for as long as you can find its hash ID), and every commit stores every file forever.  So all the information you want *is* in the repository, and you're on the right track:

> ```
> git log --oneline -- '*.class'
> ```

The problem you encounter here is that this kind of `git log` operation works by *filtering away* some commits.  That is, `git log` visits the commits—i.e., the history—but doesn't *tell you about* some of them.  The commits *are* the history, and if `git log` didn't filter some away like this, you'd get all the *non*-relevant commits.

So far, no problem, but: this kind of filtering is what Git calls *history simplfication*, and if you bring up [the `git log` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) and search for **History Simplification** ([this direct link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification) may stop working at some point, but works at the moment to go straight to it), you'll find this:

> `Default mode`
> Simplifies the history to the simplest history **explaining the final state of the tree**. [emphasis mine]

Since the "final state of the tree" has the `*.class` files *removed*, `git log` here often doesn't bother telling you about commits that added and modified the files.  They're gone!  You clearly don't care about them!

Fortunately, just a bit below that you will find:

> `--full-history`
> Same as the default mode, but does not prune some history.

So adding `--full-history` is the cure for Git's silliness here.

You may *also* want to start from *all branch and tag and remote-tracking names* (all references, really), i.e., add `--all` before the `--`.  The resulting final command is:

```
git log --oneline --full-history --all -- "*.class"
```

If you're on Windows using `CMD.EXE`, be sure to use double quotes (or no quotes) here.  From more sensible CLIs, either single or double quotes will be fine (but no-quotes may not be, depending on details).

Comment: Woooow!!!! Thanks a lot for such a great explanation, and amazing hint that did the trick!!!!

Comment: torek this question is answered 100% :) if I may aks you for one additional opinion since you're such an expert. I managed to find those commits which contained those binaries. The thing is that I copied files and commits from some other SCM platform to my Git repo. However company Bitbucket doesn't allow push of the binaries files (not allowed in our bitbucket instance). I do not have them but I suppose it still rejects the `git push` operation because of those commits which references those old commits. My quest.-is there some trick I can do (to remove perhaps those old commits from hist)?

Comment: It's very difficult to get Git to *remove* anything: it's built to do the opposite, to preserve everything forever. To remove stuff, you basically have to construct a whole new repository that's different from the original (and then be careful never to introduce them to each other, lest the shrunken one take all the commits from the fat one). To shrink a repository, use any of the various tools Out There: "the BFG", `git filter-branch` (formally obsolete now), `git filter-repo` (its replacement, not yet distributed with Git though), or others you can find.